# What does the diagonal line near the bottom of the Eastern Orthodox Cross symbolize?

Tags: eastern-orthodox, symbolism, cross

[image]

Notice the bottom of the cross, with the diagonal line. What does it represent/symbolize (if anything)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It represents the piece of wood (part of the cross) upholding or supporting the victim's feet; one can get a much clearer view of it in [icons depicting Christ's crucifixion](http://www.google.com/search?q=crucifixion+icon&tbm=isch).

Answer (score 0):

According to Russian Orthodox Tradition, the lower horizontal piece was bent by the extreme agony Christ suffered on the Cross.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others.](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites/1809#1809) In most questions, it is expected that the answer has a source. You can add a link by putting your statement in [these brackets](and your link in these parentheses).